# Android: Add TextView from one activty, to ListView in another activity through a button click

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

I have a textview in my first activity and cannot pass its content to the listview in the second. I am trying to take a food name and add it to a menu. Below is my receiving activity. Can anybody tell me how to fix this? Many thanks in advance

FoodItemActivity.java

```
public class FoodItemActivity extends Activity {

private TextView foodHeader;
private TextView foodPrice;


 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.food_layout_screen);

    // connect menuHeader to menuListHeaderTextview for the header, receives the intent from MainActivity below
    foodHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodItemHeader);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String menuItem = i.getStringExtra("childItem");
    foodHeader.setText(menuItem);

    addToOrderBtn();
    viewOrderBtn();

  }

    // add to order button
    public void addToOrderBtn(){

        Button addToOrder_Btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_addToOrder);
        addToOrder_Btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){

                foodHeader = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foodItemHeader);
                //foodPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foodItemPrice);

                String sendHeader = foodHeader.getText().toString();
                //String sendPrice = foodPrice.getText().toString();


                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(FoodItemActivity.this, OrderActivity.class);
                 myIntent.putExtra("sendHeader", sendHeader);
                 //myIntent.putExtra("sendPrice", sendPrice);
                 startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    // view order button
    public void viewOrderBtn(){

        Button viewOrder_Btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_viewOrder);
        viewOrder_Btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){

                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(FoodItemActivity.this, OrderActivity.class);
                 startActivity(myIntent);
            }

        });             
    }
```

OrderACtivity.java

```
public class OrderActivity extends ListActivity {

public ArrayList<String> orderList = new ArrayList<String>();
private String[] list;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ListView lv;
private String listItem;

@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.order_screen);

    Intent i = new Intent();
    listItem = i.getStringExtra("sendHeader");
    // adds the received sata to ArrayList orderList
    orderList.add(listItem);


    // assign lv to order_screen's ListView component order_list
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.order_list);

    // convert ArrayList orderList to Array
    list = (String[]) orderList.toArray();

    // assign adapter to "this" context, with the layout page order_list_item, and the info obtained in list
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.order_list_item, list); //R.id.order_food_name);
    // set the data behing lv to adapter
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);





  }
```

Comment: whats going wrong? have you try to log ListItem, are you receiving the value? Your question is quite vague

Comment: You're creating a new `Intent` with `Intent i = new Intent();` and then calling `listItem = i.getStringExtra("sendHeader");` - why would you think your `Intent` would have a string extra in it? If that's the code for the `Activity` receiving the data then you should be using `getIntent()` which gives you the `Intent` which was used to start that `Activity` by the first `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your Arraylist declaration which gets call each time when u pass intent its initialize again and clear last store values so you don't get previously stored values  so best way is declare that arraylist in other class and add received values to that arraylist and pass it to adapter.

Comment: Any tips on how to accomplish that?

Comment: create class inside package e.g TempValues inside that class declare public static ArrayList<String> orderList = new ArrayList<String>(); and inside your OrderActivity activity replace orderList.add(listItem); with TempValues.orderList.add(listItem);

Comment: if your issues gets resolved then accept the answer.

Comment: with my solution or any other solution?? If its resolved because of answer then accept the answer.